# A lot of divs on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to "unrender" elements which aren't visible on screen?
I have a page with a lot divs, some of them have event listeners attached to them. Above 45k divs event handlers are running very slow, so I thought maybe unrendering unnecessary element would help?

FYI - when elements have `display: none` everything works fine.

Comment: Out of interest what use case requires 45k divs on one HTML page?

Comment: You mean removing the DOM or just making hiding them? Because if you want to remove them, the code which bypasses 45k div will slow down the page too.

Comment: one way would be to implement some kind of pagination so that you _don't_ have 45k divs on a page.

Comment: This is crazy. How many months/years took that?

Comment: There's no such thing as "unrendering". Just don't output that many divs. Use server-side logic to not write out the divs you don't need.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding 45k of event listeners, you should add one event listener on a parent-div.

With jQuery you can do something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="clickable">a</div>
  <div class="clickable">a</div>
  <div class="clickable">a</div>
  <div class="clickable">a</div>
  <div class="clickable">a</div>
  <div class="clickable">a</div>
  <div class="clickable">a</div>
  <div class="clickable">a</div>
</div>
```

.

```
$("#container").on('click', '.clickable', function(e) {
  console.log($(e.target));
})
```

this should improve your javascript code.

If you still need to hide elements who a not visible you will need to calculate their positions, and that might decrease your performence

Comment: use `$(this)` instead of `$(e.target)`.

Comment: @Teemu Not as far as I understand: http://api.jquery.com/on/ under "Direct and delegated events"

Comment: "In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored. " 
But your example does the same, but jQuery have that built-in

Comment: Please take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjxaezzb/). Pay attention to the value of `this`, which always should refer to the element the event has been attached to. Then remove the selector, and run again, you then will know what I mean.

Comment: @Teemu That is just jQuery calling `.apply` with the matched element.. 
`ret = ( ( jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {} ).handle || handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );` There are only one eventhandler..

Answer (score 0):

Use divs when you need to divide (that's what divs are supposed to be used for) sections of your page from one another. Header/footer from content for instance, or individual posts on a blog.

However, you shouldn't use them when semantically where another element would make sense.  While this is not a duplicate, I think the info found here will be of use to you.  [Too Many DIVS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280039/layout-with-divs-can-you-have-too-many)